# How to remove specific section/snippet from a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pyqt

I have a PyQt stylesheet given as a `str` type where I insert it into `app.setStyleSheet()` to change CSS properties. I want to remove a specific section of code within this string, specifically this section:

```
QSlider::groove:horizontal {
    background: #32414B;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    height: 4px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

This is the entire stylesheet string

```
stylesheet = '''
/* QWidget ---------------------------------------------------------------- */

QWidget {
    background-color: #19232D;
    border: 0px solid #32414B;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    selection-background-color: #1464A0;
    selection-color: #F0F0F0;
}

QWidget:disabled {
    background-color: #19232D;
    color: #787878;
    selection-background-color: #14506E;
    selection-color: #787878;
}

QWidget:item:selected {
    background-color: #1464A0;
}

QWidget:item:hover {
    background-color: #148CD2;
    color: #32414B;
}

/* QMainWindow ------------------------------------------------------------ */
/* This adjusts the splitter in the dock widget, not qsplitter              */


QMainWindow::separator {
    background-color: #32414B;
    border: 0 solid #19232D;
    spacing: 0;
    padding: 2px;
}

QMainWindow::separator:hover {
    background-color: #505F69;
    border: 0px solid #148CD2;
}

QMainWindow::separator:horizontal {
    width: 5px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/Vsepartoolbar.png);
}

QMainWindow::separator:vertical {
    height: 5px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/Hsepartoolbar.png);
}

/* QToolTip --------------------------------------------------------------- */

QToolTip {
    background-color: #148CD2;
    border: 1px solid #19232D;
    color: #19232D;
    padding: 0;   /*remove padding, for fix combo box tooltip*/
    opacity: 230; /*reducing transparency to read better*/
}

/* QStatusBar ------------------------------------------------------------- */

QStatusBar {
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    background: #32414B; /*fixes spyder #9120,#9121*/
}

QStatusBar QToolTip {
    background-color: #148CD2;
    border: 1px solid #19232D;
    color: #19232D;
    padding: 0;   /*remove padding, for fix combo box tooltip*/
    opacity: 230; /*reducing transparency to read better*/
}

QStatusBar QLabel {
    background-color: transparent; /*fixes spyder #9120,#9121*/
}

/* QCheckBox -------------------------------------------------------------- */

QCheckBox {
    background-color: #19232D;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    spacing: 4px;
    outline: none;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}

QCheckBox:focus {
    border: none;
}

QCheckBox QWidget:disabled {
    background-color: #19232D;
    color: #787878;
}

QCheckBox::indicator {
    margin-left: 4px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/checkbox_unchecked.png);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked:hover,
QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked:focus,
QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked:pressed {
    border: none;
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/checkbox_unchecked_focus.png);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked:disabled {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/checkbox_unchecked_disabled.png);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:checked {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/checkbox_checked.png);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:checked:hover,
QCheckBox::indicator:checked:focus,
QCheckBox::indicator:checked:pressed {
    border: none;
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/checkbox_checked_focus.png);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:checked:disabled{
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/checkbox_checked_disabled.png);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:indeterminate {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/checkbox_indeterminate.png);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:indeterminate:disabled {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/checkbox_indeterminate_disabled.png);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:indeterminate:focus,
QCheckBox::indicator:indeterminate:hover,
QCheckBox::indicator:indeterminate:pressed {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/checkbox_indeterminate_focus.png);
}

/* QGroupBox -------------------------------------------------------------- */

QGroupBox {
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-top: 16px;
}



QGroupBox::title {
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    subcontrol-position: top left;
    left: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}

QGroupBox::indicator {
    margin-left: 4px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

QGroupBox::indicator {
    margin-left: 2px;
}

QGroupBox::indicator:unchecked:hover,
QGroupBox::indicator:unchecked:focus,
QGroupBox::indicator:unchecked:pressed {
    border: none;
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/checkbox_unchecked_focus.png);
}

QGroupBox::indicator:checked:hover,
QGroupBox::indicator:checked:focus,
QGroupBox::indicator:checked:pressed {
    border: none;
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/checkbox_checked_focus.png);
}

QGroupBox::indicator:checked:disabled {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/checkbox_checked_disabled.png);
}

QGroupBox::indicator:unchecked:disabled {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/checkbox_unchecked_disabled.png);
}

/* QRadioButton ----------------------------------------------------------- */

QRadioButton {
    background-color: #19232D;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    spacing: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

QRadioButton:focus {
    border: none;
}

QRadioButton:disabled {
    background-color: #19232D;
    color: #787878;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

QRadioButton QWidget {
    background-color: #19232D;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    spacing: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

QRadioButton::indicator {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

QRadioButton::indicator:unchecked {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/radio_unchecked.png);
}

QRadioButton::indicator:unchecked:hover,
QRadioButton::indicator:unchecked:focus,
QRadioButton::indicator:unchecked:pressed {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/radio_unchecked_focus.png);
}

QRadioButton::indicator:checked {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/radio_checked.png);
}

QRadioButton::indicator:checked:hover,
QRadioButton::indicator:checked:focus,
QRadioButton::indicator:checked:pressed {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/radio_checked_focus.png);
}

QRadioButton::indicator:checked:disabled {
    outline: none;
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/radio_checked_disabled.png);
}

QRadioButton::indicator:unchecked:disabled {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/radio_unchecked_disabled.png);
}

/* QMenuBar --------------------------------------------------------------- */

QMenuBar {
    background-color: #32414B;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #19232D;
    color: #F0F0F0;
}

QMenuBar:focus {
    border: 1px solid #148CD2;
}

QMenuBar::item {
    background: transparent;
    padding: 4px;
}

QMenuBar::item:selected {
    padding: 4px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0px solid #32414B;
}

QMenuBar::item:pressed {
    padding: 4px;
    border: 0px solid #32414B;
    background-color: #148CD2;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

/* QMenu ------------------------------------------------------------------ */

QMenu {
    border: 0px solid #32414B;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    margin: 0px;
}

QMenu::separator {
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #505F69;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    padding-left: 4px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

QMenu::icon {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left:4px;
}

QMenu::item {
    padding: 4px 24px 4px 24px;
    border: 1px transparent #32414B;  /* reserve space for selection border */
}

QMenu::item:selected {
    color: #F0F0F0;
}



QMenu::indicator {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    padding-left:6px;
}

/* non-exclusive indicator = check box style indicator (see QActionGroup::setExclusive) */

QMenu::indicator:non-exclusive:unchecked {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/checkbox_unchecked.png);
}

QMenu::indicator:non-exclusive:unchecked:selected {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/checkbox_unchecked_disabled.png);
}

QMenu::indicator:non-exclusive:checked {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/checkbox_checked.png);
}

QMenu::indicator:non-exclusive:checked:selected {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/checkbox_checked_disabled.png);
}

/* exclusive indicator = radio button style indicator (see QActionGroup::setExclusive) */

QMenu::indicator:exclusive:unchecked {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/radio_unchecked.png);
}

QMenu::indicator:exclusive:unchecked:selected {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/radio_unchecked_disabled.png);
}

QMenu::indicator:exclusive:checked {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/radio_checked.png);
}

QMenu::indicator:exclusive:checked:selected {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/radio_checked_disabled.png);
}

QMenu::right-arrow {
    margin: 5px;
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/right_arrow.png)
}

/* QAbstractItemView ------------------------------------------------------ */

QAbstractItemView {
    alternate-background-color: #19232D;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QAbstractItemView QLineEdit {
    padding: 2px;
}

/* QAbstractScrollArea ---------------------------------------------------- */

QAbstractScrollArea {
    background-color: #19232D;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #F0F0F0;
}

QAbstractScrollArea:disabled {
    color: #787878;
}

/* QScrollArea ------------------------------------------------------------ */

QScrollArea QWidget QWidget:disabled {
    background-color: #19232D;
}

/* QScrollBar ------------------------------------------------------------- */

QScrollBar:horizontal {
    height: 16px;
    margin: 2px 16px 2px 16px;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #19232D;
}

QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
    background-color: #787878;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    border-radius: 4px;
    min-width: 8px;

}

QScrollBar::handle:horizontal:hover {
    background-color: #148CD2;
    border: 1px solid #148CD2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    min-width: 8px;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/right_arrow_disabled.png);
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: right;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
    margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
    border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/left_arrow_disabled.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: left;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal:hover,
QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal:on {
    border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/right_arrow.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: right;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal:hover,
QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal:on {
    border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/left_arrow.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: left;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::up-arrow:horizontal,
QScrollBar::down-arrow:horizontal {
    background: none;
}

QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal,
QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal {
    background: none;
}

QScrollBar:vertical {
    background-color: #19232D;
    width: 16px;
    margin: 16px 2px 16px 2px;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background-color: #787878;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    min-height: 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QScrollBar::handle:vertical:hover {
    background-color: #148CD2;
    border: 1px solid #148CD2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    min-height: 8px;

}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/up_arrow_disabled.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/down_arrow_disabled.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover,
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:on {
    border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/up_arrow.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover,
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:on {
    border-image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/down_arrow.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical,
QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    background: none;
}

QScrollBar::add-page:vertical,
QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}

/* QTextEdit--------------------------------------------------------------- */

QTextEdit {
    background-color: #19232D;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
}

QTextEdit:hover {
    border: 1px solid #148CD2;
    color: #F0F0F0;
}

QTextEdit:selected {
    background: #1464A0;
    color: #32414B;
}

/* QPlainTextEdit --------------------------------------------------------- */

QPlainTextEdit {
    background-color: #19232D;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
}

QPlainTextEdit:hover {
    border: 1px solid #148CD2;
    color: #F0F0F0;
}

QPlainTextEdit:selected {
    background: #1464A0;
    color: #32414B;
}

/* QSizeGrip --------------------------------------------------------------- */

QSizeGrip {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/sizegrip.png);
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
}

/* QStackedWidget --------------------------------------------------------- */

QStackedWidget {
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    border: 1px solid #19232D;
}

/* QToolBar --------------------------------------------------------------- */

QToolBar {
    background-color: #32414B;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #19232D;
    padding: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

QToolBar QToolButton{
    background-color: #32414B;
}

QToolBar::handle:horizontal {
    width: 6px;
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/Hmovetoolbar.png);
}

QToolBar::handle:vertical {
    height: 6px;
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/Vmovetoolbar.png);
}

QToolBar::separator:horizontal {
    width: 3px;
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/Hsepartoolbar.png);
}

QToolBar::separator:vertical {
    height: 3px;
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/Vsepartoolbar.png);
}

QToolButton#qt_toolbar_ext_button {
    background: #32414B;
    border: 0px;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/right_arrow.png);
}

/* QAbstractSpinBox ------------------------------------------------------- */

QAbstractSpinBox {
    background-color: #19232D;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    padding-top: 2px;     /* This fix  103, 111*/
    padding-bottom: 2px;  /* This fix  103, 111*/
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    /* min-width: 5px; removed to fix 109 */
}

QAbstractSpinBox:up-button {
    background-color: transparent #19232D;
    subcontrol-origin: border;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    border-left: 1px solid #32414B;
    margin: 1px;
}

QAbstractSpinBox::up-arrow,
QAbstractSpinBox::up-arrow:disabled,
QAbstractSpinBox::up-arrow:off {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/up_arrow_disabled.png);
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
}

QAbstractSpinBox::up-arrow:hover {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/up_arrow.png);
}

QAbstractSpinBox:down-button {
    background-color: transparent #19232D;
    subcontrol-origin: border;
    subcontrol-position: bottom right;
    border-left: 1px solid #32414B;
    margin: 1px;
}

QAbstractSpinBox::down-arrow,
QAbstractSpinBox::down-arrow:disabled,
QAbstractSpinBox::down-arrow:off {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/down_arrow_disabled.png);
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
}

QAbstractSpinBox::down-arrow:hover {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/down_arrow.png);
}

QAbstractSpinBox:hover{
    border: 1px solid #148CD2;
    color: #F0F0F0;
}

QAbstractSpinBox:selected {
    background: #1464A0;
    color: #32414B;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
/* DISPLAYS --------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* QLabel ----------------------------------------------------------------- */

QLabel {
    background-color: #19232D;
    border: 0px solid #32414B;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #F0F0F0
}

QLabel::disabled {
    background-color: #19232D;
    border: 0px solid #32414B;
    color: #787878;
}

/* QTextBrowser ----------------------------------------------------------- */

QTextBrowser {
    background-color: #19232D;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QTextBrowser:disabled {
    background-color: #19232D;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    color: #787878;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QTextBrowser:hover,
QTextBrowser:!hover,
QTextBrowser::selected,
QTextBrowser::pressed {
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
}

/* QGraphicsView --------------------------------------------------------- */

QGraphicsView {
    background-color: #19232D;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QGraphicsView:disabled {
    background-color: #19232D;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    color: #787878;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QGraphicsView:hover,
QGraphicsView:!hover,
QGraphicsView::selected,
QGraphicsView::pressed {
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
}

/* QCalendarWidget -------------------------------------------------------- */

QCalendarWidget {
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QCalendarWidget:disabled {
    background-color: #19232D;
    color: #787878;
}

/* QLCDNumber ------------------------------------------------------------- */

QLCDNumber {
    background-color: #19232D;
    color: #F0F0F0;
}

QLCDNumber:disabled {
    background-color: #19232D;
    color: #787878;
}

/* QProgressBar ----------------------------------------------------------- */

QProgressBar {
    background-color: #19232D;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
}

QProgressBar:disabled {
    background-color: #19232D;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    color: #787878;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
}

QProgressBar::chunk {
    background-color: #1464A0;
    color: #19232D;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QProgressBar::chunk:disabled {
    background-color: #14506E;
    color: #787878;
    border-radius: 4px;
}


/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
/* BUTTONS ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* QPushButton ------------------------------------------------------------ */

QPushButton {
    background-color: #505F69 ;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px;
    outline: none;
}

QPushButton:disabled {
    background-color: #32414B;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    color: #787878;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px;
}


QPushButton:checked {
    background-color: #32414B;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px;
    outline: none;
}

QPushButton:checked:disabled {
    background-color: #19232D;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    color: #787878;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px;
    outline: none;
}

QPushButton::menu-indicator {
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: bottom right;
    bottom: 4px;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: #19232D;
    border: 1px solid #19232D;
}

QPushButton:hover,
QPushButton:checked:hover{
    border: 1px solid #148CD2;
    color: #F0F0F0;
}

QPushButton:pressed:hover{
    border: 1px solid #1464A0;
}

QPushButton:selected,
QPushButton:checked:selected{
    background: #1464A0;
    color: #32414B;
}

/* QToolButton ------------------------------------------------------------ */

QToolButton {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px;
}

QToolButton:checked {
    background-color: #19232D;
    border: 1px solid #19232D;
}

QToolButton:pressed {
    background-color: #19232D;
    border: 1px solid #19232D;

}

QToolButton:disabled {
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
}

QToolButton:hover,
QToolButton:checked:hover{
    border: 1px solid #148CD2;
}
QToolButton:pressed:hover{
    border: 1px solid #1464A0;
}

/* the subcontrols below are used only in the MenuButtonPopup mode */

QToolButton[popupMode="1"] {
    padding: 2px;
    padding-right: 12px;     /* only for MenuButtonPopup */
    border: 1px solid #32414B;   /* make way for the popup button */
    border-radius: 4px;
}

/* The subcontrol below is used only in the InstantPopup or DelayedPopup mode */

QToolButton[popupMode="2"] {
    padding: 2px;
    padding-right: 12px;      /* only for InstantPopup */
    border: 1px solid #32414B;    /* make way for the popup button */
}

QToolButton::menu-button {
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    /* 16px width + 4px for border = 20px allocated above */
    width: 16px;
    outline: none;
}

QToolButton::menu-button:hover,
QToolButton::menu-button:checked:hover {
    border: 1px solid #148CD2;
}

QToolButton::menu-indicator {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/down_arrow.png);
    top: -8px;     /* shift it a bit */
    left: -4px;    /* shift it a bit */
}

QToolButton::menu-arrow {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/down_arrow.png);
}

QToolButton::menu-arrow:open {
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
}

/* QCommandLinkButton ----------------------------------------------------- */

QCommandLinkButton {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

QCommandLinkButton:disabled {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #787878;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
/* INPUTS - NO FIELDS ----------------------------------------------------- */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* QCombobox -------------------------------------------------------------- */

QComboBox {
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    border-radius: 4px;
    selection-background-color: #1464A0;
    padding-top: 2px;     /* This fix  #103, #111*/
    padding-bottom: 2px;  /* This fix  #103, #111*/
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    /* min-width: 75px;  removed to fix 109 */
}

QComboBox:disabled {
    background-color: #19232D;
    color: #787878;
}

QComboBox:hover{
    border: 1px solid #148CD2;
}

QComboBox:on {
    selection-background-color: #19232D;
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    background-color: #19232D;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    selection-color: #148CD2;
    selection-background-color: #32414B;
}

QComboBox::drop-down {
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 20px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-left-color: #32414B;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/down_arrow_disabled.png);
}

QComboBox::down-arrow:on,
QComboBox::down-arrow:hover,
QComboBox::down-arrow:focus {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/down_arrow.png);
}

/* QSlider ---------------------------------------------------------------- */

QSlider:disabled {
    background: #19232D;
}

QSlider:focus {
    border: none;
}

QSlider::groove:horizontal {
    background: #32414B;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    height: 4px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::sub-page:horizontal {
    background: #1464A0;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    height: 4px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::sub-page:horizontal:disabled {
    background: #14506E;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal {
    background: #787878;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    margin: -8px 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal:hover {
    background: #148CD2;
    border: 1px solid #148CD2;
}

QSlider::groove:vertical {
    background: #32414B;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    width: 4px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::sub-page:vertical {
    background: #1464A0;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    width: 4px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::sub-page:vertical:disabled {
    background: #14506E;
}

QSlider::handle:vertical {
    background: #787878;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    margin: 0 -8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::handle:vertical:hover {
    background: #148CD2;
    border: 1px solid #148CD2;
}

/* QLine ------------------------------------------------------------------ */

QLineEdit {
    background-color: #19232D;
    padding-top: 2px;     /* This QLineEdit fix  103, 111 */
    padding-bottom: 2px;  /* This QLineEdit fix  103, 111 */
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #F0F0F0;
}

QLineEdit:disabled {
    background-color: #19232D;
    color: #787878;
}

QLineEdit:hover{
    border: 1px solid #148CD2;
    color: #F0F0F0;
}

QLineEdit:selected{
    background: #1464A0;
    color: #32414B;
}

/* QTabWiget -------------------------------------------------------------- */

QTabWidget {
    padding: 2px;
    selection-background-color: #32414B;
}

QTabWidget QFrame{
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
}

QTabWidget::pane {
    border: 1px solid #32414B;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
}

QTabWidget::pane:selected {
    background-color: #32414B;
    border: 1px solid #1464A0;
}

/* QTabBar ---------------------------------------------------------------- */

QTabBar {
    qproperty-drawBase: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 0;

    /* left: 5px; move to the right by 5px - removed for fix */
    }

QTabBar::close-button {
    border: 0;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/close.png);
}

QTabBar::close-button:hover {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/close-hover.png);
}

QTabBar::close-button:pressed {
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/close-pressed.png);
}

/* QTabBar::tab - selected ----------------------------------------------- */

QTabBar::tab:top:selected:disabled {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #14506E;
    color: #787878;
    background-color: #32414B;
}

QTabBar::tab:bottom:selected:disabled {
    border-top: 3px solid #14506E;
    color: #787878;
    background-color: #32414B;
}

QTabBar::tab:left:selected:disabled {
    border-left: 3px solid #14506E;
    color: #787878;
    background-color: #32414B;
}

QTabBar::tab:right:selected:disabled {
    border-right: 3px solid #14506E;
    color: #787878;
    background-color: #32414B;
}

/* QTabBar::tab - !selected and disabled ---------------------------------- */

QTabBar::tab:top:!selected:disabled {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #19232D;
    color: #787878;
    background-color: #19232D;
}

QTabBar::tab:bottom:!selected:disabled {
    border-top: 3px solid #19232D;
    color: #787878;
    background-color: #19232D;
}

QTabBar::tab:left:!selected:disabled {
    border-right: 3px solid #19232D;
    color: #787878;
    background-color: #19232D;
}

QTabBar::tab:right:!selected:disabled {
    border-left: 3px solid #19232D;
    color: #787878;
    background-color: #19232D;
}
'''
```

Since I'm not reading from a file, I can't use `readline()`. I already tried to use a `for` loop to iterate through and check if `QSlider::groove:horizontal` is inside but I can't figure out how to remove the remaining lines. How can I remove this snippet of CSS and return the other untouched CSS as a `str`?

```
stylesheet = 'the really big CSS stylesheet string'
def remove_qslider_tick_bug():
    # Remove snippet
    return filtered_stylesheet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find` to get the location of your substring, then Python allow string slicing the same as slicing lists. So if you want to do this all yourself you could do something like:

```
def snip_outside_str(text,start_text,end_text):
                start = text.find(start_text)
                end = text[start:].find(end_text) #fails if start_text=end_text
                end = end + start + len(end_text)
                return text[:start]+ text[end:]

stylesheet = 'the really big /*CSS*/ stylesheet string'

def remove_qslider_tick_bug(my_str, start_str='/*', end_str='*/'):

    while my_str.find(start_str)  != -1:
        my_str = snip_outside_str(my_str, start_str, end_str)

    return my_str
```

WARNING: This code is just an example of how to tackle the problem, it's going to produce some weird results when `start_str=end_str` or when `end_str` doesn't exist. So if you want to work with CSS there are libraries that can do that for you. For example: https://tinycss.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

(Disclaimer, I'm not a web guy and I've never used tinycss in anger)

Comment: This works for isolating the desired snippet, but I think OP wants to remove the snippet and return the original stylesheet string

Comment: oh yes, sorry adding the extra bits now

Comment: Is there a way to do it inside the function?